# A-frame not tracking custom image

Tags: javascript, html, ar.js

I just started trying the A-frame with AR.js to hopefully get an object to render on a piece of paper. I have tested the object and it is correctly rendered. However, when I try it with a custom image, it no longer works... I am trying to show a gltf file on a pattern. THe pattern is (in image form):[image: preview] and was made using https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html

Does anyone see anything wrong with my code as to why that pattern is not being taken by the camera as a match? Is it my code? or is it something to do with the pattern file I am trying to load?

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
</head>

<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;'>
        <a-assets>
            <a-asset-item id="mesh" src="./data/Camargue.gltf"></a-asset-item>
        </a-assets>
        <a-entity gltf-model="#mesh" rotation="0 180 0" modify-materials></a-entity>
        <a-light type="directional" color="#fff" position="-1 -5 -5" look-at="a-entity"></a-light>
        <a-light type="ambient" color="#fff" intensity="3" look-at="a-entity"></a-light>
        <a-marker-camera type="pattern" patternUrl="data/pattern-logo.patt"></a-marker-camera>
    </a-scene>

    <script>
        AFRAME.registerComponent('modify-materials', {
            init: function () {
                // Wait for model to load.
                this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {
                    // Grab the mesh / scene.
                    const obj = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
                    // Go over the submeshes and modify materials we want.
                    obj.traverse(node => {
                        if (node.name.indexOf('Loggia-frame') !== -1) {
                            var environment = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().setPath('data/HDR/').load(
                                [
                                    'posx.jpg', 'negx.jpg', 'posy.jpg', 'negy.jpg', 'posz.jpg', 'negz.jpg'
                                ]
                            );

                            environment.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
                            environment.mapping = THREE.CubeReflectionMapping;

                            var material = node.material;
                            material.envMap = environment;
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please create and try your .patt file with rgb(240,240,240) background and with high resolution image that named "renson" ?

Comment: I forgot to update this issue as resolved, I have solved it by adding my loaded gltf file in the body of the marker. I was using an outdated method.